# How to use Adaptive Rejection Sampling to Update Alpha in iGMM

Tags: gaussian

I am wondering how can I use ARS (adaptive rejection sampling) in dirichlet process mixture model (infinite Gaussian mixture model) as described by Rasmussen (https://www.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs281/papers/rasmussen-1999a.pdf)

Using equation (15), I have introduced the log and derive the derivative of the log of equation 15. However, I can't figure out what's the next step.